# JDBC connection object returns null in Servlet/Web

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, servlets

I'm stuck with a servlet problem – my database connection is turning up null. The weird part is, the same database code works fine in another class. I've double-checked my configuration, loaded the JDBC driver, and tested it on Tomcat, but the connection in the servlet stays stubbornly null.

```
Type Exception Report

Message Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "connection" is null

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "connection" is null
```

SingletonConnection.java:

```
    public class SingletonConnection {
    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CATALOGUE";
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";
    private static Connection connection;
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

ProduitdaoImp.java

```
    public class ProduitdaoImp implements IProduitdao {
    @Override
    public List<Produit> chercher(String mc) {
        Connection connection = SingletonConnection.getConnection();
    
        List<Produit> produits = new ArrayList<Produit>();
        try {
    
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM PRODUITS                                                                      WHERE DESIGNATION LIKE ?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "%" + mc + "%");
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Produit p = new Produit();
                p.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
                p.setPrix(rs.getDouble("PRIX"));
                p.setQuantite(rs.getLong("QUANTITE"));
                p.setDesignation(rs.getString("DESIGNATION"));
                produits.add(p);
    
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return produits;
    }  
}
```

ControleurServlet.java

```
public class ControleurServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public IProduitdao iProduitdao;
    
    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        iProduitdao = new ProduitdaoImp();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws   ServletException, IOException {
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        if (path.equals("/index.do")) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Produits.jsp").forward(request, response);
    
        } else if (path.equals("/chercher.do")) {
            String mot = request.getParameter("motcle");
    
            ProduitModel produitModel = new ProduitModel();
    
            produitModel.setMotCle(mot);
    
            List<Produit> produits = iProduitdao.chercher(mot);
            produitModel.setProduits(produits);
            request.setAttribute("model", produitModel);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Produits.jsp").forward(request, response);
    
        }
    
    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }
}
```

Produits.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Produits</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
<div>
    <div>
        <div > Recherche des produits</div>
        <div ></div>
        <form method="get" action="chercher.do">
        <label>Mot CLe</label>
            <input type="text" name="motcle"/>

        <button type="submit">Chercher</button>
        </form>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <th>ID</th><th>DESIGNATIONNs</th><th>PRIX</th><th>QUANTITE</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${model.produits}" var="p">
                <tr>
                    <td>${p.id}</td>
                    <td>${p.designation}</td>
                    <td>${p.prix}</td>
                    <td>${p.quantite}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You’re on the wrong track here. You shouldn’t be even thinking about a connection as a singleton, and you should be using the Context lookup system to obtain your database connections from the container every time you need one.

Comment: Plus, you're not looking at thrown exceptions

Comment: Don't try to manage connection on the static field. Many threads can access them at the same time disasterly.

Comment: Did your `connection.prepareStatement` line get truncated? Incorrect syntax.

Comment: Worth learning Spring Boot with its JDBC client.  Use that and a connection pool.  They'll make your relational SQL life much easier.

Comment: NB That `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")` line hasn't been needed since 2006.

Answer (score 2):

A database connection is like a [facial tissue](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_tissue)… Grab a fresh one, use it, and dispose. Never use a single connection simultaneously within or across threads. Your singleton approach is ill-advised, and doomed to fail in confusing ways.

Store your connection credentials details, such as username, password, server address, port number, all in a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object. Keep that `DataSource` object available while your app runs. Ask that cached `DataSource` object for a new connection each time your app needs access to the database.

Here is [one tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-datasource-jdbc-datasource-example) on `DataSource`. You will also find many examples by me and others if you search Stack Overflow. And see, [*Why do we use a DataSource instead of a DriverManager?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15198319/642706).

While learning, you can hard-code your connection credentials. In real work, we externalize those details so they can be changed without needing to recompile the app. Use [JNDI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) to retrieve the credentials as a `DataSource` object. Tomcat has a feature where it can produce the `DataSource` object in a JNDI-compliant manner.

By the way, `Class.forName` to load a JDBC driver has been unnecessary for many years. In modern Java, JDBC drivers auto-load via [SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface).

I suspect you are using an outdated and misinformed tutorial on JDBC.

To learn more, [search Stack Overflow](https://www.ecosia.org/search?tts=st_asaf_ipad&q=java%20jdbc%20DataSource%20%20site%3Astackoverflow.com%20mysql). You will find much info including full working example apps, some authored by me.

Tip: Use `static` reluctantly. It’s not object-oriented. Frequent use may indicate poor design.

Answer (score 2):

[@Basil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77708738/139985) and others have given you **lots of good advice**, and if you had followed it you wouldn't have gotten into this mess.

But what is actually going wrong?

If you are getting NPEs when trying to use the connection (supposedly) returned by `getConnection()`:

- that means that the `private connection` field is `null`,
- that means that the `static` init block hasn't assigned a value to `connection`, and
- that means that an exception must have been thrown and caught in the `try` ... `catch`, and the `e.printStackTrace()` output must have gone to Tomcat's standard output.

So, look in the server logs (including the "catalina.out" output file) for the output from the `e.printStackTrace()` call.  It should be a stacktrace for a `ClassNotFoundException` or an `SQLException`.  And it will have happened before the NPE.  That stacktrace will tell you what *actually* went wrong to cause the NPE.

---

But follow Basil's advice!  And also, **log** your exceptions rather than using `printStackTrace()`.